# Solspace Calendar: custom fields not outputting

Tags: custom-field, plugin-solspacecalendar

I'm unable to get custom fields to output using Solspace Calendar on Craft3. I am not getting any errors indicating that the field does not exist, it's just not outputting. The field is a Redactor type.

```
{% set event = craft.calendar.event(segment2, {targetDate: occurrenceDate}) %}

{% if event %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9">
        <h2>{{ event.title }}</h2> {# THIS OUTPUTS #}
        {{ event.eventDescription }} {# THIS CUSTOM FIELD DOES NOT OUTPUT AND THERE ARE NO ERRORS #}
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

UPDATE: I tried using the field handles that are in the Solspace Calendar templates (location and description), but neither of those output:

```
{% if event['location'] is defined %}
    <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <td>
            {{ event.location }}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue and will be resolved in Beta 4 coming out today (March 15, 2018). Sorry for the trouble.